# Java passing a value to an array without altering original

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 arrays of objects and i want to pass an object from one array to the other without altering the original.

```
Array1[3] = Array2[3];
```

Array1 would be altered while Array2 would not be.

I have a class named Level and an array of levels named levelList; I also have a copy of this array named cleanLevelList so i can reload the original level.

when i call:

```
levelList[1] = cleanLevelList[1];
```

it works once then the next time it is called it once again alters cleanLevelList;

I have tried cleanLevelList.clone();

Comment: ...and the question is ? :)

Comment: What do you mean by "altered". Do you mean the array itself, or the objects in the array?

Comment: what makes you assuming that Array2 might get altered with the assignment?

Comment: The object in array 2 would not be altered and array1[3] would be replaced with array2[3]

Comment: If you want changes to `Array1[3]` not to reflect to `Array2[3]`, then you need to call a copy constructor: `Array1[3] = new Foo(Array2[3]);`

Comment: What kind of array do you have - which array of what?

Comment: @jlordo: thats what clone() is for.

Comment: i tried that and it is still altering the original array.. It works one time and then the next time it alters it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by design. The single-equals means set the left operand to the right operand. The 4th element of Array1 is set to the value of the fourth element of Array2. This changes the contents of the array, though not the structure.

If you're trying to do a comparison, you'll want to use `==` for "is equal?" or `!=` for "is not equal?". If you want Array2[3] to be set to the value of Array1[3] then just reverse the operands.